# Codeiginiter get all rows from mysql database that start with tom

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get all rows in mysql database that start with character "tom" using codeigniter  but the result does not match what I want

My code

Controller

```
public function get_merchant_name(){

    $names = $this->model_merchants->getMerchantName("tom");
    print_r($names);
}
```

Model

```
public function getMerchantName($value)
{
    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM tbl_merchants WHERE first_name like  ? or  last_name like  ? or other_names like  ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array("%$value", "%$value", "%$value"));
    return  $query->result_array() ;

}
```

Comment: Your query is looking for values that _end_ with `tom`. You should change the bindings to `"$value%"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
public function getMerchantName($value){
    $this->db->select('*');
    if ($value) {
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('first_name', $value);
        $this->db->group_end();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_merchants');
    return $query->result();
}
```